# Make only one column editable and capture edits in the server

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to make only one column editable and when the user makes changes, the changes have to be captured in the server side. Further, when the user clicks an update button, new results based on the edits have to be populated in the table. In the code below, if I make *editable = TRUE*, it works fine. However, I disable all the columns except the one of interest, the edits are not reflected in the server and clicking the update button does not make any changes. Why is disabling edits of all except one does not work for edits to be captured on the server side?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

initial_budget = tibble(country = c('us', 'fr', 'de'),
                        budget = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('allocated'),
  actionButton("update", "update")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(initial_budget)
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    df(mutate(df(), mrA = budget * 0.25, mrB = budget * 0.75))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('allocated')
  
  observeEvent(input[["allocated_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["allocated_cell_edit"]]
    print(info)
    df(editData(df(), info, proxy))
    print(df)
  })
  
output$allocated <- DT::renderDataTable(df(), editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(1,3, 4))))
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

initial_budget = tibble(country = c('us', 'fr', 'de'),
                        budget = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('allocated'),
  actionButton("update", "update")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv  <- reactiveValues(df=initial_budget)

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    if (input$update <1) rv$df <- initial_budget %>% mutate( mrA = budget * 0.25, mrB = budget * 0.75)
    else rv$df <- rv$df[,c(1:2)] %>% mutate( mrA = budget * 0.25, mrB = budget * 0.75)
    print(rv$df)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('allocated')
  
  observeEvent(input[["allocated_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["allocated_cell_edit"]]
    str(info)
    print(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    rv$df[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rv$df[i, j])
    #rv$df1 <- editData(rv$df, info, proxy)
    print(rv$df)
  })
  
  output$allocated <- renderDT({
        datatable(
          rv$df,
          editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(1,3,4))),
          options = list(dom = 'frtBip')
        )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```